# API V3 CustomSalesTax

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am currently testing V3 of the API with QBO.

Creating an invoice that includes tax is fine if the TxnTaxDetail includes a TxnTaxCodeRef that exists in QBO.

However I noticed when pulling the list of tax codes from QBO that there is a special one called CustomSalesTax.

Can this CustomSalesTax be used to add a custom sales tax to an invoice ?. For instance, I'd supply the TotalTax = 1000, TaxLine.Amount=1000, TaxLine.TaxLineDetail.PercentBased=false in order to add 1000 of tax to the invoice.

Thanks
Fernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CustomSalesTax** is a special id that represents the old US tax model. So this can be used to update any old transactions that are tied to old US tax model. Cannot create new transactions using  this CustomSalesTax.

Thanks

Comment: Manas, thank you for the response. Is it possible in V3 to create a transaction, say an invoice, that uses a custom tax code- i.e. not a tax code/rate in QBO ?.

Comment: If custom tax code can be created from QBO UI then it can be referenced in the transaction as well. You can refer the V3 docs for this.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/0500_v3_supported_entities_and_operations
(Tax code/rate can't be created using API). thanks.

Comment: Manas, thanks again. I am familiar with the documentation, and I am asking in this forum to close the gaps in the documentation. The motivation of my question is based on our experience with V2; in V2 you could simply populate either a TaxRate or TaxAmt in the request, and therefore you could either apply a tax rate or a tax amount to an invoice. It seems to me that in V3, the tax code and tax rates used to populate a request can only be those defined in QBO. Is this what you are saying ?

Comment: yes. As mentioned earlier, TaxCode and TaxRate entities don't support create operation yet.

Comment: Thank you Manas. Got it now. So the tax code and rate used in a transaction must always be those defined in QB. But once the create is implemented we will be able to create new ones, so they are in QB, and then reference them in a transaction.